# Using JQuery to alter html link while doing ajax update

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have what is essentially the equivalent to a "like" button, aka, a link that when you click on it, a message to the server should be sent to increment the counter on the page. Is there a built in widget for this? or is it code your own, i.e. it should basically do this:

- Switch the "Like" link to say "Unlike"
- Increment the counter.
- POST to the server saying the counter should increment.
- If server returns error, unincrement the counter and switch "Unlike" back to like.

Comment: You have to do it by tour own code, btw, what have you tried so far, post your code with specific question, on where you have stucked.

Comment: @RecoveringSince2003 No point writing code if jQuery already has this code. Hence my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this example fiddle I created just now: http://jsfiddle.net/jxc876/yGCTH/

Pretty simple :

0) setup HTML

```
<div id="comment-123">This is a comment
    <div class="likeCount">0 likes</div> 
     <a href="#" class="like">+like</a>
    <a href="#" class="dislike">-dislike</a>
</div>
```

1) Register a function on the link

```
$('.like').click(doLike);
```

2) send data off to server

```
    $.post('/echo/json/', data, callback, 'json');
```

3) After the server replies, get the new counter, & update the display

```
function callback(reply) {
    var comment = '#comment-' + reply.commentId;
    $(comment + ' .likeCount').text(reply.likeCount);
    $(comment + ' a').toggle();    
}
```